# Web Hosting Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have downloaded a free portfolio theme and installed it here at http://navkaar.x50x.net/test/, but, I have encountered with the following error, however header.php is still exist and upload with other files at FTP.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/u772590232/public_html
/test/index.php on line 1
```

How can I run the theme smoothly?

Comment: Are we talking about Word Press?

Comment: yes, this is Grid theme - http://www.dessign.net/grid-theme-responsive/

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install a WordPress theme without first installing WordPress. As you've just discovered, this doesn't work. Install WordPress and get familiar with it first.